# Unable to Access one SourceForge Project but Able to Access the Other

Tags: git, sourceforge

I have two projects on Sourceforge:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/therandomizerwpf/

https://sourceforge.net/projects/ergobreaker/

I'm using Sourcetree to access the git repositories and while I was able to setup the one for ergobreaker, the one for the randomizer does not work giving the following error:

[image: Error Message]

Both of these are under the same GitHub login so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Do you mean sourceforge project or stackoverflow project? If you meant sourceforge, please edit your question.

Comment: Sorry, meant Sourceforge

Comment: Are you sure that the path "`/git/p/therandomizerwpf/code the randomizerwpf-code`" is valid and present on GitHub? That path looks a little suspect/wonky to me - probably a copy/paste issue in editing your local repo config file...

Comment: I should have mentioned that I'm not very familiar with Git as I use TFS for work but I copied the address from the SourceForge Code page.

Comment: @twalberg, you were right.  "the randomizerwpf-code" should not have been at the end of hte path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My original path was incorrect as @twalberg pointed out.  I forgot to remove "the randomizerwpf-code" from the end of the path.